# Validation using JSR-303 with more then one regex pattern and using property file for validation message

Tags: java, regex

I am using validation using JSR-303 like this:

```
public class Person {
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
  @Pattern(regexp="(^[^_*!$^|\\\\:;<>\"]*$)")
  private String name;
}
```

**Added  following messages in our messages.properties file**

```
Pattern.person.name=Invalid name
```

Now requirement is we need to show different message "Name should not be blank" if user provide all trailing spaces in this field.
I am thinking to use @Pattern.List for this but i am confuse how i differentiate  this in property file like which message is for which pattern
and plase share the regex pattern (Regular Expression)also which do not also trailing spaces
One solution which i found over internet

```
 public class Person {
        @NotNull
    @Pattern.List({
            @Pattern(regexp = "(^[^_*!$^|\\\\:;<>\"]*$)", message = "{person.name.specialcharacter.not.allowed}"),
            @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=\\s*\\S).*$", message = "{person.name.not.blank}") })

  private String name;
    }
```

and in xml file i added

```
<mvc:annotation-driven  validator="beanValidator"/>
    <bean id="beanValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
             <property name="validationMessageSource" ref ="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
            <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" >
        <property name="basenames" value="classpath:localization/${spring.profiles.active}/messages,classpath:localization/messages"  />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

now when i entered spaces in this filed is  showed me {person.name.not.blank}
it is not giving translated message
where I am wrong??
In messages_en.properties file i added

```
person.name.not.blank=name can not be blank
person.name.specialcharacter.not.allowed=name can not have  special character
```

Comment: Have a look at negative [look around](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). With those you could use the expression `^(?!\s)[xxx]*(?<!\s)$` where `[xxx]` is your character class. `^(?!\s)` means there must not be whitespace right at the start and `(?<!\s)$` there must not be whitespace right before the end.

Comment: How can i get localized messages, Do i miss something?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with JSR-303 but does adding special characters result in a localized message? Did you update all relevant files? For example, your post contains ` message = "{person.name.special.character.not.allowed}"` but `person.name.specialcharacter.not.allowed=name can not have  special character` - note the missing dot in `specialcharacter`. If special characters don't work either, try removing the locale from the file, i.e. `messages.properties`.

Comment: (specialcharacter)It is just typo mistake i updated this